# How do I end screen -x?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

I am using `screen -x` to monitor the process of a rsync.
Now I am scared I will end the rsync process in the terminal.

Is it safe to end `screen -x` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you run `screen -x` (note the space), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is **not safe** and **will be passed to a process inside screen**, be it rsync of anything else. In particular, rsync will be stopped by the break signal.

To detach a running screen without interruption of the process inside you need to type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd>, i.e. hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, while holding it it press <kbd>A</kbd> and release, and then press <kbd>D</kbd> and release, and then release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. You will see the message like `[detached from 46865.pts-5.uc-s4m75657]`, where the last part is the socket name.

You can reattach it by running `screen -r <socket>` or `screen -x <socket>` afterwards, where `<socket>` is the socket name from previous. If you have only one free socket, you can just run `screen -r` or `screen -x`. You can list all the current sockets with `screen -list`.

Comment: Thank you, that CTRL+A and D worked.